# index error for setting datagridview cell value

Tags: c#, datagridview, indexing

I'm getting a frustrating error that I'm pretty sure is something simple, but I cannot figure out what.

Here is my function:

```
public void setDistanceCellValue(int value, int row, int column)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Row: " + row + " Column: " + column + " Value: " + value);
                logGrid.Rows[row].Cells[column].Value = value.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occurred: {0}" + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + "Row: " + row + " Column: " + column + " Value: " + value, ex.Message));
    }
}
```

Where the `logGrid` value setting line is what is erroring out with "Index is out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index."

I've been checking and checking and my grid has six rows and 8 columns, and the function is getting called on say row 2 column 3 (hence all the debugging code). For the life of my I can't figure out why it is saying I'm using a negative index or an index large than 5 for the `e.rowIndex` or 7 for `e.columnIndex`.

Help me if you can.

Comment: can you show us the loop in which this function is being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexes range from **0 to N-1**, not from **1 to N**.

---

EDIT:

Two suggestions

1. Add additional debugging code before your existing `Console.WriteLine`

```cs
   Console.WriteLine("Row Count: {0}", logGrid.Rows.Count);
   Console.WriteLine("Cell Count: {0}", logGrid.Rows[row].Cells.Count);
```

1. Check the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to see if it set as you expected.

Comment: yes, that is why for 6 total rows, the index goes from 0 to 5. but I can't explain why setting the value for a cell in the middle (it would be easier to debug if it was only happening on the 0th or Nth index) still throws that error?

Comment: Where does this `e.rowIndex` come from. I do not see any `e` in your code. Is the error happening somewhere else?

Comment: that is simply from `private void logGrid_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)` to provide the row and column index of the cell that was double clicked.

Comment: I do not really see where the problem is, however I added two suggestions to my answer that might help you to track down the problem.